# maximum no of equal elements in the array after n transformation

Tags: arrays, algorithm

You have an array containing n elements. At any move, you choose two indices i and j,  i not equals j and increment value at one index and decrease value at other index. You can make this move any number of times. We need  is the maximum number of elements which can have the same value (after any number of moves).
Example for 1,2,3,4 answer is 3 since we can have at most 3 elements equal after applying the moves any number of times. But i am searching for the algorithm to do that so needed help.

Comment: That's a very interesting question.  I would love to hear what you have done so far to solve it.

Comment: Not clear..how you came to answer 3 for the array (1,2,3,4) ?

Comment: hello Scott Hunter, I didn't gittin any algo for this but 
for the example above 1,2,3,4 for i=0,j=3 array becomes 2,2,3,3 after the move. Then i=0,j=1 or i=2,j=3 the array becomes 1,3,3,3 or 2,2,2,4
and this is the maximum no of equal no that we can have..:)

Comment: @ArunMu read the previous comment for clarification.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not programming. Try math.stackexchange.com instead.


Comment: @Barmar That's a hazy line you're crossing.

Comment: @Barmar,i need help for the steps or method to solve the problem and by the ways, programming is all about maths/logic i think.

Comment: Any different than this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131799/minimum-number-of-transformation-steps-required-to-make-all-elements-of-an-array ?

Comment: @ArunMu that's a different question in which we increment or decrement all the elements but here we select the two i,j i!=j and increment one by 1 and decrement the other one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated, this doesn't take much of an algorithm. If you can do it as many times as you want, you should **always** be able to get a result with either `N` or `N-1` elements equal (where `N` is the size of the input array).

Take the sum of the input. For example, in your case: `sum(1,2,3,4) = 10`.

If `sum % N == 0`, the answer is `N`. Any time before that, you'll have at least one element higher than `sum/N` and at least one lower. Increment the low, decrement the high.

Else the answer is `N-1`. The final set can have `N-1` elements equal to `(int)sum/N` and the last element will be the remainder from the original sum. You can use that last element as a "spare" to increment/decrement whichever other elements you want.

Since you don't have to actually find the transformations, the end result is O(N). You just take the sum and mod it by N to check which answer to give. There's no use recursing or searching for "averaging pairs" unless you want to find the sequence of steps that lead to the answer..

Comment: @Geobits.thanks sir :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a very ineffective algorithm - but you could try some sort of dynamic programming.

```
def elems(array, previous_attempts = []):
    # Get a list of all the possible arrays (after transforming the current array)
    # and remove all of the arrays we have seen so far.
    possible_arrays = possibilities(array) - previous_attempts

    # If there are no more possible, return the number of elements the array
    # has in common.
    if possible_arrays is empty:
        return num_in_common(array)

    # Otherwise, for all the possibilities find the one that creates the maximum
    # amount of elements in common.
    max = 0
    for a in possible_arrays:
        # This is a recursive call that calculates the score for the possibility.
        # It also keeps track of the current state so we don't revisit it.
        score = elems(a, previous_attempts.append(array))
        if score > max:
            max = score
    return max
```

Comment: hello sir, i don't know python, i am a c/c++ programmer. so sir can u plz explain what are u trying to do with these lines above.Thanks. :)

Comment: @RaunakTalwar It's really just pseudo-code. The algorithm draws upon http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming where we check each state and keep only the maximum value found so far. I will add comments to the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of occurrences of each value in the array (Lets call the array `A` of size `N`). Let the maximal number of occurrences of any value in `A` be `max` (may be several values), you are only interested in the values that appeared `max` times, as other values can't surpass `max+1` appearances by the suggested method.

Extreme cases:

1. if `max=N` the answer is `N`
2. if `max=N-1` the answer is `N-1`

In all the other cases, for each value `V` that appeared `max` times, you are trying to find two other values that have an average of `V` but don't equal `V`. if they exist, then the answer is `max+2` (you can increment them so they both will be equal to `V`). if no such indexes `i` and `j` exist, the answer is `max+1` (you can increment any two other values until one of them will be equal to `V`).

**EDIT:**
This answer assumes that you only choose `i` and `j` once and then increase/decrease them as much as you like (I guess I misinterpreted).

Comment: Sir can u apply the method you are telling for the example given in the question 1,2,3,4.. i think it goes to the otherwise case ?..plz explain :)

Comment: In the case you mentioned all values appear `max` time, which is exactly once, but only 2 and 3 have other two indexes that have an average of 2 and 3, in case of 2 it's 1 and 3, and in case of 3 it's 2 and 4. so the answer is `max+2` which is 3 (finding this for one them is sufficient for giving the answer).